# Django error PermissionDenied has no attribute set_cookie

Tags: python, django

In my django application i have the below code

```
if not exist:
   return PermissionDenied
```

This line will returns following error

```
type object 'PermissionDenied' has no attribute 'set_cookie'
```

Can any one help me please

Comment: try to raise the `PermissionDenied` instead of return

Answer (score 1):

Import this file in your file:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
```

Raise Permission Denied as follows:

```
if not exist:
    raise PermissionDenied()
```